# How do I store a Nested Map structure in a Guava Cache

Tags: java, spring-boot, caching, guava

I have to store a nested map structure in the cache right now in our application we are using google guava  with a single key and value but I have to store a nested map

here is what I have tried

```
private final EmployeeService employeeService;
public Supplier<Map<String, Map<String, List<String>>>> cachedMap = Suppliers.memoizeWithExpiration(
        new Supplier<Map<String, Map<String, List<String>>>>() {
            @Override
            public Map<String, Map<String, List<String>>> get() {
                return getEmployeeDetails();
            }
        }, 10, TimeUnit.MINUTES
);

public employeeCache(EmployeeService employeeService) {
    this.employeeService = employeeService;
}



Map<String, Map<String, List<String>>> getEmployeeDetails() throws MessagingException, IOException {
    ArrayList<String> testemplist = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList("Emp3245630","Emp3269682","Emp693526","Emp0800933","Emp1817416"));

    return employeeService.getEmployeeDetails(testemplist);
}
```

I am not sure this is the right implementation my code is not working

can anyone help me to archive this requirement to add nested map in google guava

Comment: Storing a nested map isn't really different from storing anything else.

Comment: don't understand your point

Comment: @saravananG Your code doesn't even compile.